# Remove variable characters in a txt file

Tags: powershell

I want to import a .txt file with some domains and get some informations about with three nslookup commands. To import the data after check in a .csv, I just need the server adresses not the priotiry and so on.
The final question is, how can I remove all of the numbers between a ";" and ","

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content outEOF.txt).Replace(\"nameserver = \", \"\") > tmpOutNS.txt"
powershell -command "(Get-Content tmpOutNS.txt).Replace(\"mail exchanger = \", \"\") > tmpOutME.txt"
powershell -command "(Get-Content tmpOutME.txt).Replace(\"MX preference = \", \"\") > tmpOutMX.txt"
powershell -command "(Get-Content tmpOutMX.txt).Replace(\"`t\", \";\") > tmpOutTab.txt"
powershell -command "(Get-Content tmpOutTab.txt).Replace(\";`\"v\", \"`\"v\") > tmpOutSPF.txt"
```

Here is the current export:

```
domain.de;50, MXIN2.somemailer.de; domain.de;10, mail.somemailer.de; domain.de;ns1.virtualhosts.de; domain.de;ns2.virtualhosts.de;
```

And I want it as

```
domain.de;MXIN2.somemailer.de; domain.de;mail.somemailer.de; domain.de;ns1.virtualhosts.de; domain.de;ns2.virtualhosts.de;
```

Comment: Try `$export -replace ';\d+,', ';'`

Comment: If the spaces matter, we can build off of Theo's expression: `$export -replace ';\d+,', ';' -replace '(?<=(;|^)[^\.]*?\.[^\.]*?;)\s'`

Comment: Theo Thank you. That has fixed my problem.
AdminOfThings Thank you too. But the spaces does not matter ;)